# How to reference a subclass as a type parameter?

Tags: java, generics, reference

## Is there a way to use a subclass of the current class as a type parameter for a generic class ?

I'm not very sure how to expose my problem so I'll go with an example :

### Example

My `Connection` object is responsible for sending and receiving a certain type of (subclass of) `Message` over the network (only reproducing the relevant parts here) :

```
public class Connection<M extends Message> {
    public void send(M mes) {
        ...
    }
}
```

My `Message` object is an abstract class superclassing all kinds of messages sent over the network.

```
public abstract class Message {
    private transient Connection<?> conn;

    public void send() {
        this.conn.send(this);
    }
}
```

Of course, I have several subclasses of `Message`.

### Problem

My problem comes from the `Connection<?> conn` property of `Message` : in it's current state eclipse tells me that

> The method send(capture#7-of ?) in the type Connection< capture#7-of ?> is not applicable for the arguments (Message)

What type parameter should I use for `Connection` so that it is compatible with any subclass of `Message` ?

### What I tried

I tried declaring `Message` as :

```
public abstract class Message<M extends Message<M>> {
    private transient Connection<M> conn;
    ...
}
```

And then I would have :

```
public class MessageA extends Message<MessageA> {
    ...
}
```

as a subclass.

But this is a big hassle (I have a lot of generic classes using subclasses of `Message` as type parameters) and it doesn't seem to be the proper way to handle it.

Comment: What about `Connection<Message> conn;`?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza yes of course that's it ! Thanks for your help, guess I shouldn't be coding so late at night ...
Feel free to post an answer and I'll accept it !

Comment: If that's really a suitable answer, it suggests that the parameter of `send` in `Connection` should probably be of type `Message` and not `M`;  it further suggests (less strongly) that the `Connection` class need not have a type parameter at all.

Comment: How does Message get to know about its Connection? In other words, how does 'conn' field get populated?

Comment: @davmac : the `Connection` does need a type parameter because (from a design pov) it should only work with a single subclass of `Message`. Specifically, `Connection#send` uses other objects with the same type parameter (`M`).
However I do understand there's a flaw in this design, but it does the trick for now. I welcome any other idea !

@Vlad : it knows about it via a setter (hidden here).

Comment: Declaring it as class `Message<M extends Message<M>>` would not help you -- you still cannot do `this.conn.send(this);`, as `this` is type `Message<M>`, which is not a subtype of `M`, the parameter type of `conn.send()`.

Comment: @as0n 'does need a type parameter because (from a design pov) it should only work with a single subclass of Message' - but you can enforce this through your design without using the type system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Connection<Message>`:

```
public abstract class Message {
    private transient Connection<Message> conn;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get an `M` to give to `conn.send()`, you need an abstract method that will give you an `M`, which subclasses override to provide.

```
public abstract class Message<M> {
    abstract M getMessage();
    private transient Connection<M> conn;

    public void send() {
        conn.send(getMessage());
    }
}

public class MessageA extends Message<MessageA> {
    MessageA getMessage() {
        return this;
    }
}
```